# Php form post method not sending data

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I have a simple HTML form, which is actually working well on my localhost and in few servers. But last time I put it in my code, I understood that it doesn't send data with `POST`, although I have written the `method="post"`. This is first time I meet this problem, and I don't know if it is from my side or from server.
When I dump `GLOBAL` param `$_SERVER` in my localhost, the param `REQUEST_METHOD` is `POST`, but when I dump it on server it is `GET`. I also tried to change the method in `.htaccess`, but no result. 
Here is my form:

```
<form action="/auth/login" method="post">
      <div id="error">
            <?
              if (isset($errors)) {
                 foreach ($errors as $error) {
                      echo $error . "<br>";
                  }
               }
               if (isset($invalid)) {
                    echo $invalid;
                }
               ?>
      </div>
      <div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Login:</div>
      <div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;">
           <input name="login" class="form-login" type="text"/>
       </div>
       <div id="login-box-name">Password:</div>
       <div id="login-box-field">
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-login"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="image" src="/images/login-btn.png" width="103" height="42" style="margin-left:90px;" />
   </form>
```

And on server when I print `$_POST` or `$_POST['login']` they are empty, although I have passed params.

```
 public function action_login() {  
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_SERVER); // this is returns server data, where REQUEST_METHOD is GET on current server, but POST in my local 
        var_dump($_POST); // this is empty
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

Is that from server or hosting configuration?

Comment: can you use any framework ??? or core php ??

Comment: I am using Kohana framework, and I have used the sam e code for few other projects and it worked great, this project and code is also working on my local server, but it doesn't send POST data on the current server. My question was if that can be from server configuration?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<form action="auth/login" method="POST">
          <div id="error">
                <?
                  if (isset($errors)) {
                     foreach ($errors as $error) {
                          echo $error . "<br>";
                      }
                   }
                   if (isset($invalid)) {
                        echo $invalid;
                    }
                   ?>
          </div>
          <div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Login:</div>
          <div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;">
               <input name="login" class="form-login" type="text"/>
           </div>
           <div id="login-box-name">Password:</div>
           <div id="login-box-field">
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-login"/>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" src="/images/login-btn.png" width="103" height="42" style="margin-left:90px;" value="save" />
       </form>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work.  input type image is similar to submit. So the result is the same.

Comment: In your action change this /auth/login  to this  auth/login

Comment: My action is longer then here actually, but I didn't wrote at all, the point is this code is working in my local server and in few others, but it doesn't on current. My question was if that can be from server configuration?

Answer (score -1):

you are missing key word : type="submit"

Comment: instead of submit I am using type="image" which is similar to submit.I have tried also with submit, but the result is the same